# What is Successful Ratio of Climbing K2?

Tags: hiking, mountains, pakistan, mountain-climbing

I just want to assess the difficulty of hiking on K2 with historical perspective. So I want to know How many people tried to climb K2 and how many of them successfully climbed, How many died and how many were came back safe?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Outdoor. Suggest to move it to http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When you say "hike" are you talking about "mountain climbing"? Not all hiking is about trying to reach the summit. And of course especially in alpine conditions of snow and ice I'm not sure it's really "hiking" at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to this link](http://www.8000ers.com/cms/download.html?func=startdown&id=150) there where 306 people climbing K2, 30 of which died. This would result in a fatality rate of ca. 10%. This table only includes actual successful ascents.

[This list lists 80 fatalities](http://www.8000ers.com/cms/download.html?func=startdown&id=179) including those who died during the ascent. I couldn't find any number of attempted ascents though.

On another note the success rate [seems to have gotten higher](http://www.8000ers.com/cms/download.html?func=startdown&id=161) those last years than in the past.